# Possible to have two apps respond to the the same base URL using Firebase

Tags: firebase, branch.io, firebase-dynamic-links

I currently have a scenario where I have app A and a sister app called app B. I would like to have app A and app B respond to a Firebase dynamic link and be able to either app A or app B opened depending on which app the user has on their phone.

Is it possible to achieve this in Firebase. So if I have www.mydomain.com/data/myData. If person A has app A on their phone, the when person A presses www.mydomain.com/data/myData, the app A opens. But if person B who has app B installed on their phone press www.mydomain.com/data/myData then app B opens. Is this possible at all on FireBase?

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is have two apps be able to acquire information from say a URL like, www.mydomain.com/data/myData and use myData as needed in each separate app.

Think of it as two apps "sharing" data between each other.

From an iOS perspective, based on [this tutorial](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/) and this [response from branch on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790747/can-ios-universal-app-link-support-multiple-apps-using-the-same-domain), clearly this is possible but does Firebase cater for an app being able to respond to two custom URLs.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this all the way through.*

This should be possible with Dynamic Links. When you visit the Overview section of the Firebase console, you have the option to add multiple apps to a Firebase single project. Both apps are correctly inserted into the `apple-app-site-association` file, which means every Dynamic Link in that Firebase project will be a  Universal Link that **should** correctly triggers either app.

There are a couple caveats to be aware of:

1. Behavior if **both** apps are installed on a device is undefined.
2. For obvious reasons, you have to pick just one of the App Store pages as the app-not-installed fallback location. A workaround for this could be sending the user to a non-store page.